# Is it acceptable to say "full of baloney" in an essay?

Tags: word-usage

I am a high school IB student taking AP English Literature. In my opinion, Brave Orchid is full of some balderdash talk-stories, which I would like to express as "full of baloney." Is this acceptable in an essay about *The Woman Warrior*?

> The reader is already past the idea that Brave Orchid's talk-stories are full of baloney, but the idea is now forming in Kingston.

Update: The reason for saying the "talk-stories are full of baloney" or any substitute is that they are actually made up stories that Brave Orchid told her children, not my opinion. In one of the stories she tells her only daughter she had two siblings who died in China. It is more of a fact than my opinion that her stories are fictitious (thanks for that word by the way). Think of Santa Claus flying to 2 billion houses in one night with the aid of nine reindeer--we're talking about *that* kind of baloney.

Comment: It's doubtful anyone here can tell you with much certainty. Did you ask your teacher?

Comment: It is currently summer break, as this is a summer assignment, in my county and my teacher is unknown.

Comment: if you check in a dictionary, it's categorized as "informal".  If it's an essay, it's not acceptable for most teachers. This question belongs in ELL.

Comment: I think it's acceptable, but it's an annoying phrase to me and sounds old-fashioned.

Comment: [Baloney](http://www.tfd.com/baloney) is marked as slang in the Am. Heritage Dictionary 5th ed. suggesting against its use in formal literature, so I'm marking this as general ref. Also, the *full of baloney* variation is also usually used to imply that a person speaking is a chronic liar if I recall correctly. The "[lot of baloney](http://idioms.tfd.com/baloney)" variant would be better to restrict your claim to questionable material if you must use this idiom, but I recommend using the word [fictitious](http://webstersdictionary1828.com/Dictionary/fictitious) instead of either phrase.

Comment: @P.Obertelli What is ELL? If it is English Language Learners I can assure you I know no other language than English and I would not consider writing AP Lit essays as learning the English language.

Comment: @Tonepoet Thank you for your response! I'll fit _fictitious_ into my essay instead.

Comment: @Tonepoet *Fictitious* is not a substitute for baloney. The former means not literally true, and the latter means nonsensical. Great works of fiction are of course fictitious, but they're not full of baloney.

Comment: You've attracted a close vote and a downvote (neither of them mine), and the reason is that your question doesn't hinge on English usage. I'm guessing you know what "full of baloney" means, and you're just soliciting opinions on its suitability in a formal setting. Alas, strictly opinion-based answers are considered out of scope here.

Comment: From Wikipedia: "*The Woman Warrior* has been reported by the Modern Language Association as the most commonly taught text in modern university education.* Oy.

Comment: Instead of looking for a euphemism for "baloney" or "bullshit" or whatever other abstract term, try being more **specific**. Say just what you *mean* by it being baloney. Say more specifically *in what ways* it is baloney. Just saying something is baloney is little more than name-calling. You will likely improve your essay a bit if you dig down into the specifics of what makes it baloney. IOW, go inside *this specific* sausage factory to analyze what *this specific* baloney is made of. Think of [Louis Agassiz and the fish](http://philosophy.lander.edu/intro/introbook2.1/x426.html).

Comment: @deadrat The word fictitious has slightly different connotations in contexts where we of denying purportedly true claims, than it does when discussing myths and entertainment which are known to be false. I made my suggestion of the word fictitious based on uses closer to [fictitious claims](https://www.law.cornell.edu/uscode/text/18/287) or [fictitious rumors](http://dictionary.reverso.net/english-cobuild/fictitious%20claim), which somebody may deny by saying they are "full of nonsense", than great fiction. Rather than saying a claim is "full of baloney", I might say it's "utterly fictitious".

Comment: @deadrat For future questions, where should I post any opinion-based questions?

Comment: @DavisRash I'm sorry if this is a bother but ["*primarily* opinion based" questions are not topical anywhere on the Stack Exchange network as a matter of overarching policy](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/184154/closing-changes-on-hold-unclear-too-broad-opinion-based-off-topic-reasons). I'm not sure, but I think [Quora](https://www.quora.com/) is the next best place you can go to ask those sorts of questions. However, there is some room for asking about differences of opinion here, [depending upon how the question can be answered.](http://english.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask)

Comment: I was just trying to explain the responses you're getting. (You're up to 4 close votes.) But post away. I'll be glad to provide my oh-so-worthwhile opinions.  I also recommend englishforums.com. You may get the same share of condescension there, but they tend not to call you out of bounds.

Comment: @Tonepoet I could be convinced by evidence. Got any? Because your links don't help your case. *Fictitious claims* are false claims; *fictitious rumors* are false rumors. Myths are "utterly fictitious" by definition. Some may provide valuable lessons for all their fiction; others are just full of baloney.

Comment: @deadrat Not immediately on hand if that wasn't sufficient. Since comments aren't for extended discussion, I feel uncomfortable taking this beyond what we have here but [if you're willing to go to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/43170/what-a-bunch-of-utterly-fictitious-baloney) I might be able to scrounge up some for you.

Answer (score -2):

Strictly from the point of view of English usage, the relevant part of your question is whether something which is full of balderdash can be described as 'full of baloney.' I do not touch your opinions.

Both the words, balderdash and baloney refer only to nonsense. Baloney is a stronger word meant for 'pretentious nonsense.'The Merriam Webster's Collegiate Dictionary makes it clear that it is used as a generalized expression of disagreement.

There is no place for such harsh words in any constructive literary criticism.